# InvalidCastException in LINQ to entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to query a `DBSet` with Linq, but an `InvalidCastException` is thrown:

> "... type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery
>   1[Cercami.Model.Articolo]' on type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet
>   1[Cercami.Model.Articolo]'."

Below the query:

```
private DbSet<Articolo> FiltraArticoliPerRichiestaDaDB(int id)
{
    DbSet<Articolo> Result = (DbSet<Articolo>)from Art in DB.Articoli
                                               where Art.Fk_Richiesta == id
                                               select Art;
    return Result;
}
```

Where DB.Articoli is a `DBSet<Articolo>`

Any help?

Comment: Why are you trying to return a `DbSet<T>` and not just a plain `IEnumerable<T>` or even `IQueryable<T>`? Do you know what a `DbSet` is?

Comment: Because i woluld like to have 2 different "DBSet<Articolo>", the first is the one from Entity framework, the second is a temporary set, so i can make some operation (compare and modify) and finally send the modified DbSet to the model. I was thining it's useful to use the same types for articolo (is a db table) created from framework. Maybe it was a wrong idea?!?

Comment: You can't send `DbSet` object around like that, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes, maybe i'm in a wrong way, i see i cannot create a new DbSet too. What i'm trying to do is what i tried to explain in previous post: i would like to have a second temporary set to manually fill (without framework) and finally update the db in entity framework with that.

Comment: Ok, maybe it's better to go back to the big problem.  I have a dB table (Articoli). What i need is to compare the rows with another set of rows i get from a procedure. After compare i update the db.  So, easy with `List<>` (get from db into list, create a new list, compare list1 with list2, etc.) but i'm trying to use entity framework and the strong typed class.

Answer (score 5):

The following query:

```
from Art in DB.Articoli
where Art.Fk_Richiesta == id
select Art;
```

would return an `IEnumerable<Articolo>`. That being said it cannot be casted to a `DbSet<Articolo>`.

Furthermore, I think that you might want this:

```
public IEnumerable<Articolo> FiltraArticoliPerRichiestaDaDB(int id)
{
    var arts = from Art in DB.Articoli
               where Art.Fk_Richiesta == id
               select Art;

    return arts;
}
```

I changed also the access modifier of the method, since I thought that it should had been a public (accessible) method. If this is not the case, you can just changed it back to `private`.

Comment: I don't think doing `AddRange` just to return a `DbSet` is a good idea, things could get very confusing if the caller then does a `SaveChanges`.

Comment: @DavidG I see what you mean, but how would add the arts to the set that will return? This is why suggested the use of `AddRange`.

Comment: Well you don't! A `DbSet` isn't meant to have a set of values, it's meant to represent the list of objects that can be queried from the database.

Comment: Correct ! However I don't see the reason of `arts` without `AddRange`. You suggest even remove this?

Comment: I think OP doesn't want to return a DbSet really, I'm guessing it's just a lack of understanding.